Setting width of slurs which extend across line breaks using Musixtex
It is needed to configure the width of slurs which extend across line breaks using Musixtex. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 5pt 2pt -20pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B I \B V2 \B I6 \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{4} {3}}} \B I \B V \B I \B V \B VI7 \B IV6 \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{5 6} {3 4}}} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{{4-3} {5\rule[0.6ex]{2.4mm}{1pt}}}} \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.25cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\generalsignature{-3}
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}2}
\instrumentnumber{1}
%\setinterinstrument{1}{12pt}%espacio entre Voz y Piano
\interstaff{11}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%
\stafftopmarg7\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
%\staffbotmarg5\Interligne% set verticle space in one staff score
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
%\smallmusicsize
\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip%
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}%
\NOtes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\NOtes\zhl{M}\hu{=b}|\zhl{g}\hu{k}\en\bar%
\NOtes\zhl{L}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\NOtes\zhl{K}\hu{=b}|\zhl{g}\hu{m}\en\bar%\roffset{1.5}{
\NOtes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\NOtes\zhl{N}\hu{d}|\zhl{g}\hu{=i}\en\bar%
\NOtes\zhl{J}\hu{e}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\def\atnextline{\Liftslur16}%
\NOtes\zhl{N}\hu{=b}|\issluru1g\zhl{g}\breakslur1k\hu{k}\en%
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}2}%
\alaligne%
\NOtes\zwh{a}\hu{c}|\tsslur1{g}\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\NOtes\hu{c}|\zhl{f}\hu{l}\en\bar%
\NOtes\zwh{N}\hu{=b}\zcharnote{-6}{\hspace{-2.1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{CCC}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{g}\wh{k}\en%
\NOtes\nolyr\issluru2c\hu{c}|\hl{h}\en\bar%
\NOtes\zwh{N}\tsslur2{c}\hu{c}\nolyr\zcharnote{-6}{\hspace{-2.1cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{CCD}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\wh{k}\en%
\NOtes\hu{=b}|\en\bar%
\NOtes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:


According to me, MusiXTeX does what is reasonable in writing music (at least in this case). The slur could even be extended to the left.
I wonder whether your question is a theoretic one: the slur should be down and not up in this case.
Anyway: you can use a work-around:
\NOtes\zhl{J}\hu{e}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
    %\def\atnextline{\Liftslur16}% not needed here
    \NOtes\zhl{N}\hu{=b}|\issluru1g\zhl{g}% \breakslur1g not needed here
    \hu{k}\qsk\tslur1k\en% ended the slur at the end of the line
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}2}%
    \alaligne%
    \addspace{-1\afterruleskip}% to start the "new" slur immediately after the meter fraction, slur starts a little lower, because of the curve of the slur in the first line
\NOtes\qsk\zwh{a}\hu{c}|\hbsk\qsk\isluru1j\hsk\tsslur1{g}\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en% added space for the start of the "new" slur, which starts before the note

I hope this satisfies your needs.

